# Erro Consulta Oracle

Tags: query, oracle

Galera, ao executar a consulta abaixo, está ocorrendo o seguinte erro. Pela análise, o erro ocorre quando eu coloco o sum. Por qual motivo?

> "ORA-00918: coluna definida de maneira ambígua
>   00918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action: Erro na linha: 4 Coluna: 35"

Segue consulta.

```
select
  e.nm_fantasia_estab ESTABELECIMENTO,
  t.ds_caixa CAIXA,
  sum(tasy.obter_valor_trans_financ(nr_sequencia, 'E')) VL_ENTRADA, -- Esse 
  tasy.obter_valor_trans_financ é uma função
  nvl(d.vl_saldo_inicial,'0') SALDO_INICIAL,
  nvl(d.vl_saldo,'0')SALDO_FINAL
from tasy.caixa t
  left join tasy.estabelecimento e on e.cd_estabelecimento = t.cd_estabelecimento
  left join tasy.caixa_saldo_diario d on d.nr_seq_caixa = t.nr_sequencia
  left join tasy.transacao_financeira f on f.NR_SEQUENCIA = t.NR_SEQUENCIA
where t.cd_estabelecimento = 241 
group by e.nm_fantasia_estab, t.ds_caixa, nvl(d.vl_saldo_inicial,'0'), nvl(d.vl_saldo,'0');
```

Comment: Confere essa função do tasy, pode estar duplicando algum campo no select, normalmente acontece quando é adicionado algum filtro e acaba duplicando, se nao for la, em algum lugar aí ta sendo duplicado, talvez até nos left joins

Comment: Não seria essa nr_sequencia ? Se ela existir em mais de uma tabela, você tem que colocar a referência de qual tabela ela está vindo, para retirar a ambiguidade.

Comment: isso @AiltonBayma, deu certo, era isso. Obrigadão